# How to foreach radio groups inside div wrappers and get selected values using jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

If none of the radio box was selected,return 0,if selected , return the selected value

```
<div class="radiogroup">A.
    <input type="radio" name=a1 value="1">$item[2]
    <br/>B.
    <input type="radio" name=a1 value="2">$item[3]
    <br/>C.
    <input type="radio" name=a1 value="3">$item[4]
    <br/>D.
    <input type="radio" name=a1 value="4">$item[5]
    <br/>E.
    <input type="radio" name=a1 value="0">Not sure
    <br/>
</div>
<div class="radiogroup">A.
    <input type="radio" name=a2 value="1">$item[2]
    <br/>B.
    <input type="radio" name=a2 value="2">$item[3]
    <br/>C.
    <input type="radio" name=a2 value="3">$item[4]
    <br/>D.
    <input type="radio" name=a2 value="4">$item[5]
    <br/>E.
    <input type="radio" name=a2 value="0">Not sure
    <br/>
</div>
<div class="radiogroup">A.
    <input type="radio" name=a3 value="1">$item[2]
    <br/>B.
    <input type="radio" name=a3 value="2">$item[3]
    <br/>C.
    <input type="radio" name=a3 value="3">$item[4]
    <br/>D.
    <input type="radio" name=a3 value="4">$item[5]
    <br/>E.
    <input type="radio" name=a3 value="0">Not sure
    <br/>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var arr = new array();
        var k = 0;
        $(".radiogroup").each(function () {
            if ($(this."input:radio:checked").length == 0) {
                arr[k++] = 0;
            } else {
                arr[k++] = $(this."input:radio:checked").val();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

What I'm stucking in is I do not know how to using "this" to select radio groups inside a div wrapper,for example,if I need to alert each checked value,I want to do it this way,it didn't work though :

```
$(".radiogroup").each(function () {
    alert($(this.input: radio: checked).val());

});
```

The number of radio group is uncertain until the html code is finally generated,so the name=a1,name =a2 stops to a number that I do not even know,which means it's impossible to use name as a variable in the loop

I need to select checked radio box inside each div wrapper,with no id for each radio,how to do that right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
 if ($(this."input:radio:checked").length == 0) {
```

to

```
 if ($(this).find("input[type=radio]:checked").length == 0) {
```

and

```
arr[k++] = $(this."input:radio:checked").val();
```

to

```
arr[k++] = $(this).find("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
```

Comment: Thanks very much,that works for me,using find method is the right way!

Comment: Also this code works for me: alert($(this).find("input:radio:checked").val());What the difference between this to "input[type=radio]:checked",under what situation should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the lines that say

`$(this."input:radio:checked")`

to

`$(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked"`

and

`var arr = new array();`

to either one of the following:

```
var arr = new Array();
var arr = [];
```

That'll fix it.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNpDr/1/) that has a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(".radiogroup").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).children("input[type='radio']:checked").val());
});
```